# Getting TRAC to run on IIS7

Tags: python, iis, trac

Im trying to get Trac upp and running on my IIS/w2008 server using this FAQ: [TracOnWindowsIisAjp](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindowsIisAjp)

Everything upp until "3. Install Tomcat AJP Connector for IIS" works ok.
I then define my directories as : C:\wwwroot\trac.evju.biz\AJP\, in the bin catalog I place the dll file, and 3 config files with this content:

isapi_redirect-1.2.26.properties
    # Configuration file for the ISAPI Redirector

```
# The path to the ISAPI Redirector Extension, relative to the website
# This must be in a virtual directory with execute privileges
extension_uri=/AJP/isapi_redirect-1.2.26.dll

# Full path to the log file for the ISAPI Redirector
log_file=C:\wwwroot\trac.evju.biz\AJP\logs\isapi_redirect.log

# Log level (debug, info, warn, error or trace)
log_level=info

# Full path to the workers.properties file
worker_file=C:\wwwroot\trac.evju.biz\AJP\conf\workers.properties

# Full path to the uriworkermap.properties file
worker_mount_file=C:\wwwroot\trac.evju.biz\AJP\conf\uriworkermap.properties
```

workers.properties

```
# Define 1 real worker
worker.list=trac
# Set properties for trac (ajp13)
worker.trac.type=ajp13
worker.trac.host=localhost
worker.trac.port=8009
worker.trac.socket_keepalive=0
```

uriworkermap.properties

```
/C:\wwwroot\trac.evju.biz\irm\*=trac
```

Then I run into problems :

- Define a virtual directory named AJP-Connector, pointing to your bin subdirectory, with permissions to execute executables (not only scripts).

I defined a virtual directory named AJP, pointing it to the bin subdirectory, but I can't find any way of give it execute permissions

And the rest of the instructions obviously don't quite apply to IIS7

- Allow execution of the DLL as Web
  Service Extension
- In the IIS Manager, open Web Service Extensions.
- Define a new Web Service Extension called AJP-Connector (or whatever you want).
- Add C:\AJP-Connector\bin\isapi_redirect-1.2.26.dll to the required files (replace "C:\AJP-Connector" with your actual directory).
- Set extension status to Allowed.

I tried adding the dll as a ISAPI extension, this resulted in a web.config file in the bin catalog with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <remove name="ISAPI-dll" />
            <add name="AJP" path="*.ajp" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\wwwroot\trac.evju.biz\AJP\bin\isapi_redirect-1.2.26.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Execute" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this question from an unrelated Google search. Odd how that happens...
IIS7 supports FastCGI natively, I'd highly recommend using that over AJP. If you're still watching this question leave a comment and I'll follow up with details of how to install.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still looking to implement this, but I've found no good info on how to use fastCGI.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff Mc - I'm actually looking at setting trac on IIS7 and stumbled across this thread, just as you did. I would love to know the details on using FastCGI as well as any of the other gotchas with trac on IIS7.